# How do I create circle div with arrow show to the next circle

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

how do I make a div with an arrow like a step or flow process.
Below is the image like I want to do:

[image]

```
<div class="container" style="margin-top: 20px;">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <span class="fa-stack fa-4x">
        <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x text-primary"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
      </span>
      <h4 class="service-heading">1. First Step</h4>
      <p class="text-muted">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. </p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <span class="fa-stack fa-4x">
        <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x text-primary"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
      </span>
      <h4 class="service-heading">2. Second Step</h4>
      <p class="text-muted">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. </p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <span class="fa-stack fa-4x">
        <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x text-primary"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
      </span>
      <h4 class="service-heading">3. Third Step</h4>
      <p class="text-muted">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is the **[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/saf21/84gm2ecs/)** of my code.

Comment: depends on your flow. whether you are showing each step on different page or on the same page?

Comment: You can use a `pseudoelement`

Comment: if you're asking for building such shapes : you can make it easily with SVG

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a simple way you can create arrows with CSS using only pseudo elements. In the code below I have created a class `.arrow` that holds all the arrow's parts (body and head). Using [`:before`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/::before) and [`:after`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/::after) you can create both body and head. Then you can use some `border-radius` rules to style the tip of your body (right side, the one touching the head of the arrow).

```css
.arrow {
  width: 100px;
  height: 10px;
  position: relative;
}

.arrow:before {
    content: " ";
    width: 114px;
    height: 5px;
    background-color: black;
    display: inline-block;
    top: 4px;
    position: absolute;
    border-top-right-radius: 30%;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 30%;
}

.arrow:after {
    content: " ";
    display: inline-block;
    font-style: normal;
    position: absolute;
    width: 0.6em;
    height: 0.6em;
    border-right: 0.2em solid black;
    border-top: 0.2em solid black;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    margin-left: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="arrow"></div>
```

You can also achieve a similar result with SVG (credit goes to [VanseoDesign](http://vanseodesign.com/web-design/svg-markers/)). While this method gives better results it's quite difficult to manipulate and use in an HTML page in my opinion. CSS is far lighter and easier to modify.

```html
<svg width="600px" height="100px">
  <defs>
    <marker id="arrow" markerWidth="10" markerHeight="10" refX="0" refY="3" orient="auto" markerUnits="strokeWidth">
      <path d="M0,0 L0,6 L9,3 z" fill="black" />
    </marker>
  </defs>

  <line x1="50" y1="50" x2="250" y2="50" stroke="black" stroke-width="5" marker-end="url(#arrow)" />
</svg>
```

Also, [UTF-8 arrows](https://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_utf_arrows.asp) can be a solution but that's the least adaptable: length can't be changed. So by changing the `font-size` of the character you're also changing the head's size.

```css
.arrow>p {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 200px;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px
}
```

```html
<div class="arrow">
  <p>&#8594;</p>
  <p>&#x2192;</p>
  <p>&rarr;</p>
</div>
```

If I were you I would 100% go with CSS. Here's the modified [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/umg8ta65/). You will notice than on when changing to a different window size Bootstrap will adjust the spacing between your logo containers. This will in turn make the arrows too short... This is can be fixed with some media queries and some more CSS.

Comment: Wow, there is a lot of way to do it. Awesome info and idea here. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it in many ways.

Best to use SVG, Read [here](http://vanseodesign.com/web-design/svg-markers/) & [here](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/svg/marker-element.html)

or

**Pure CSS**

```css
.RightArrow {
  width: 50%;
  position: relative;
}

.line {
  margin-top: 8px;
  width: 97%;
  background: blue;
  height: 0.3em;
  float: left;
  position: absolute;
}

.point {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 10px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 10px solid transparent;
  border-left: 37px solid blue;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="RightArrow">
  <div class="line"></div>
  <div class="point"></div>
</div>
```

**Using font**

```css
div {
  font-size: 150px;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div>&#8594;</div>

<div title="U+21A3"></div>
```